# LandTrendr module for Earth Engine (LT-GEE) returns unexpected negative values

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, landtrendr

I want to extract the spectral response for all pixels within an aoi using GEE and Landtrendr. I've followed the [documentation](https://emapr.github.io/LT-GEE/index.html) for this using the recommended parameters with no issues. My problem occurs when I export the data, I noticed that bands 1-3 and 5 are all positive (expected) but band 4 is negative for all pixels and all years I'm interested in (not expected). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Why would band 4 result in negative values using this script?

[GEE script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fdwalshe99%2FFires%3ALandTrendr)

Comment: To access your script one need to have a GEE account ! That will not help people investigate your question. Please provide it in a no strings attached way if possible.

Comment: The problem lies in GEE/Landtrendr. As in, you need to know GEE syntax and have access to it in order to solve this problem. Sorry.

Comment: @Walshe_d, please share the "users/dwalshe99/Fires" repo publicly so I can view the code. Also, the better place for this question/concern is a [GitHub issue on the LT-GEE repo](https://github.com/eMapR/LT-GEE/issues/new). Please post your issue there and I'll investigate.